# Как называется приём, когда я описываю действие, которое совершаю?

Tags: общие-вопросы, терминология

Если вместо "Добро пожаловать!" я говорю "Приветствую вас..." (то есть описываю действие, которое совершаю) или "Благодарю" вместо "Спасибо" и т. п., то как называется этот приём?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы говорите о *перформативах*. Эти единицы не описывают действительность, а сами по себе являются действиями.

Известный пример: «Я обещаю» — это лишь констатация действия (его исполнение), перформатив. Истинностная оценка в данном случае невозможна, что есть одно из важных свойств перформативов.

Видео с рассказом И. Б. Левонтиной на «Постнауке»: https://postnauka.ru/video/6720.

Статья в Лингвистическом энциклопедическом словаре: http://tapemark.narod.ru/les/372c.html.